# Office.js Excel > chart.getImage() Error when in Collapsed Group

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

The `chart.getImage()` method causes the error below when in a Group (Data > Outline > Group) when that Group is Collapsed/Hidden.

I use `chart.getImage()` to get the base64 encoded image so charts can be programmatically inserted into Word/PowerPoint documents.

This feature is part of the Excel-to-Word Document Automation Add-In. Users want to be able to get the images even if collapsed in a group.

Error occurs in both Excel for Windows and Excel Online (and probably Mac)

This maybe related to [Office.js Excel Online > chart.getImage() errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563146/office-js-excel-online-chart-getimage-errors)

Is this a bug that can be fixed (or will it just not be supported)? Is there a known workaround?

To reproduce the error in ScriptLab):

```
function run() {
    Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        var chart = ctx.workbook
            .worksheets.getItem("Sheet1")
            .charts.getItem("Chart1");

        var image = chart.getImage();

        return ctx.sync().then(function () {
            console.log("done");
        });

    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

Error Details:

```
{
    "name": "OfficeExtension.Error",
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "message": "There was an internal error while processing the request.",
    "traceMessages": [],
    "innerError": null,
    "debugInfo": {
        "code": "GeneralException",
        "message": "There was an internal error while processing the request.",
        "errorLocation": "Chart.getImage",
        "statement": "chart.getImage(undefined, undefined, undefined);",
        "surroundingStatements": [
            "var workbook=context.workbook;",
            "var worksheets=workbook.worksheets;",
            "var worksheet=worksheets.getItem(\"{54698F7A-3FA1-4058-AD3B-96EF1019AE15}\");",
            "var charts=worksheet.charts;",
            "var chart=charts.getItem(\"{015E9BD6-3F08-4E97-B18F-CCC65EEC17DB}\");",
            "// >>>>>", "chart.getImage(undefined, undefined, undefined);",
            "// <<<<<", "var chart1=charts.getItem(\"{6D2803F9-8B28-49CE-9C30-3DA6942867BD}\");",
            "chart1.getImage(undefined, undefined, undefined);",
            "var chart2=charts.getItem(\"{718E8A3F-00AF-4850-B63F-327C473391C2}\");",
            "chart2.getImage(undefined, undefined, undefined);",
            "var chart3=charts.getItem(\"{2169D771-1AE2-4BE9-8780-8B46C06CEBA9}\");"
        ]
    },
    "stack": "..."
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
"GeneralException: There was an internal error while processing the request.
 at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:219258)
 at ai (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:264887)
 at ft (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:264974)
 at d (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:264794) 
 at c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:21:263490)"
```

Image to show how to Collapse Group. To create Group: Data > Outline > Group
[image: Image to show how to Collapse Group]

Comment: Do you have a sample worksheet for use with the sample code?

Comment: I added image to show how to create and collapse group because I think error can occur in any workbook with any chart that is in collapsed rows or columns.